# how to run serp node client

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer, mern

I'm extremely newbie at Node js. Please let me know how can i work with this node client https://www.npmjs.com/package/serp

```
const serp = require("serp");

var options = {
  host : "google.fr",
  qs : {
    q : "test",
    filter : 0,
    pws : 0
  },
  num : 100
};

const links = await serp.search(options);
```

When I run this the code, I receive the following error

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

VERY grateful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring functions there is an option to add an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) property. This will make the function [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

This enables the `await` property inside the function and allows the code to wait for a task to be completed before moving forward.

Example of declaring an asynchronous function:

```js
// Declare the function
async function search() {
    // Run asynchronous code
    const serp = require("serp");

    var options = {
        host : "google.fr",
        qs : {
            q: "test",
            filter: 0,
            pws: 0
        },
        num : 100
    };

    const links = await serp.search(options);
}

// Run the function
search();
```